# HTML - Container id or class

Tags: html, standards

When writing HTML, what is the industry standard regarding a Container div?
Is it more popular to have a Container id, or use a container class which I add to the divs I wish to inherit the features?

For example:

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
       ...etc
    </div>
</body>
```

or

```
<body>
    <div id="main" class="container">
        ...etc
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Still getting used to the site. Thank you for editing my post for readability; I appreciate it.

Comment: Sure thing, you can see what I've changed and apply in your future posts. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know that there is an industry standard. If it's a container, you should have only one so an ID makes sense. You can use classes and IDs however you see fit, the bigger challenge is having cleanly-written, well-stacking rules that apply to the design you're working with.

**Edit:** Your question just updated -- it'd be better to have `id="container"` and then `class="home"`, `class="about"`, etc. as needed. This would make for a neater stylesheet and would give you the option of simply overwriting #container rules if you need to.

Comment: Hmmm, thats pretty interesting..food for thought.  Thanks Matt.

Answer (score 3):

Setting an id of container would be most appropriate because you should only have one container.  Setting the class = container would imply that more than one container existed.  Since a container is designed to wrap all of your page content you should only have 1.

Answer (score 2):

Giving an element an id, implies that that element is unique.
In your case, a container div is usually unique and therefore an id would do.

A class is used when you want multiple items to have the same styling.
Giving different items the same id, is a violation to the w3c standards.

I think this is something you should decide for yourself, I've always used the above way.

Comment: Sorry,to be clear, I am aware of the differences between class and id. I thought there may be an instance whereby you may want to use the same container in multiple places (header and footer) but not in the main content.

Answer (score 1):

HTML document can have several containers, all sharing some style and each with some unique style.

So best practice is giving each both class and ID:

```
<div id="Header" class="container">
    ...header goes here...
</div>
<div id="Menu" class="container">
    ...menu goes here...
</div>
<div id="Contents" class="container">
    ...main contents come here...
</div>
```

Comment: That is along the lines of what I was thinking, would the use of the word "container" in this instance not be confusing?

Comment: Not all all, by having it you say "this element acts as container to some more elements" and can apply similar style to all containers.